# What is a good 3D graphics program for making a solid bounded by smooth surfaces?

Tags: geometry, 3d, visualization

I'm trying to make a nice graphic of a 3-dimensional shape, but do not have experience doing this so I'm looking for a good application that suits my purposes. Ultimately I want a good figure that I can rotate around, and insert pictures of into a LaTeX document.

The shape can be described as a region bounded by 10 smooth surfaces. I can write the equations for the surfaces. Two of them are flat and the others are quadratic.

Another way to describe the shape is by taking cross sections. The two flat surfaces that bound it are parallel and on opposite sides of the shape. Taking cross sections parallel to these gives simple polygons with flat edges.

Could someone recommend a program in which I could use one of the above two descriptions to get a nice graphic of my shape? Ideally I'd like something with color so I could color surfaces to show gluings.

I've been messing around with SketchUp, which is pretty cool but doesn't seem meant for math. It's also not straightforward to fill in non-planar regions, but I'm still messing around with that in the meantime.

Comment: If you've got access to it (and that may be a big _if_)  Mathematica is a good tool for the job. In particular, you can define regions using inequalities rather than having to tediously parametrize them.

Comment: I don't have access to Mathematica currently. I see that I can get a free 15-day trial though. That would probably be enough to get this project done -- just a shame to learn how to use something and then lose access again.

Comment: If you don't have institutional access to Mathematica, there are probably open-source options of similar utility.

Comment: I think the closest open-source approximation to Mathematica is [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), which can do [various kinds of 3D plots](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/) like [parametric surfaces](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/parametric_plot3d.html) and [implicit surfaces](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plot3d/sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_plot3d.html).

Comment: I would guess that if you actually include the equations in your question, some people may be tempted in giving their favorite software a try to see whether it is up to the task, and will report back if they are happy with the results.

Comment: My apologies for not responding faster to this helpful commentary, I've been messing with SketchUp obsessively and getting something that seems good enough. But I am going to look at the Sage packages recommended. One of these days (or months) I need to just buck up and learn Sage enough to not have to make posts like this.

Comment: For a small number of static images, if you (or someone you work with) already knew Mathematica code, you could use https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing the comments,
I used Mathematica's `RegionPlot3D` to make the image
below for the posting
[Sofa in a snaky 3D corridor](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246914/6094):

---

[image: SofaCut]

---

Comment: For future reference, [this question and its answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48486/484) are useful for making nicer plots of 3D shapes with sharp edges, without having to excessively increase the resolution of `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: @Rahul: Excellent--Thanks!

Comment: Mathematica's RegionPlot3D does seem to be the consensus among mathematicians for what to use for this. It's also ideal for generating a file for 3D printing.